# Custom directive doesn't get updated inside cellTemplate of ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am using a custom directive named `flag` inside the `cellTemplate` of `ui-grid`. This directive just accepts a country name (USA or CANADA), and displays its corresponding flag. The directive works fine when the page loads for the first time. However, later even if I change the value of flag to anything, the custom directive doesn't update and display the new flag. Not sure what am I missing.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gGTtL4CWLCtfwplJpDQt?p=preview)

Comment: Please check the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directive gets compiled once! You need to watch the attribute or set a two way binding!

```
app.directive('flag', function() {
  var flags = {
    USA: 'https://github.com/hjnilsson/country-flags/raw/master/png100px/us.png',
    CANADA: 'https://github.com/hjnilsson/country-flags/raw/master/png100px/ca.png'
  };

  return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
          flag: "@"
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          scope.$watch('flag', function(newValue, oldValue){
              angular.element(elem).attr('src', flags[newValue]);
          });
      }
  };
});
```

working plunkr ==> http://plnkr.co/edit/dcHDMEY8MpQnCnm99aDd?p=preview

Comment: Is there a reason why ui-grid does this?

Comment: It has nothing to do with ui-grid. Angular directives work this way! Anyway I saw in console that ui-grid has problems: it try to update the scope with a custom apply method, but it doesn't exist! I'd try with a newer version!